# How to define AWS Glue Settings in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue

So I can log into AWS console and -> Glue -> Settings on the left panel -> define my policy like { Version:.... Statement:[...]}

How to achieve this in terraform?

The existing terraform resources like `aws_glue_catalog_database` or `aws_glue_catalog_table` etc do NOT seem to

1) take in a policy input
2) apply the policy to global Glue settings

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opinion is to have individual IAM roles setup and associate each Terraform resource with its corresponding IAM role. This will give you flexibility of choosing the policies you want for the resource giving you granularity.

Or You could have a global IAM role with all the policies that will be applicable for all the Glue resources you create.